# iText7: Images with transparent backgrounds in generated Pdf documents have dark halos when printed

Tags: vb.net, pdf, png, itext7

[image: Digital image of the generated document]

*Digital Image of the Pdf Document*

[image: Image of the document after printing]

*The Pdf Document after printing*

I am using iText7 in Vb.net to generate Pdf documents, the contents of which can vary. When an image with a transparent background is placed in the document, the transparent pixels can still be seen when printed.

My question is: is there something I'm overlooking in iText when placing these images in a Pdf document?

I've looked around online for answers, but iText7 doesn't have much documentation beyond barebones API.

I'm adding the images in a pretty basic manner - ImageData to Image, and adding it to the Pdf document's layout canvas:

```
Dim sImagepath as string = "c:\whereImagesIs\imageFile.png"
Dim oPdfImage as iText.IO.Image.ImageData = iText.IO.Image.ImageDataFactory.Create(sImagepath)
Dim oImage As New iText.Layout.Element.Image(oPdfImage)
DocumentLayoutCanvas.Add(oImage)
```

The image(s) in the resulting Pdf document look proper while on screen, but when the document is printed, the images' transparent parts appear a shade darker than the underlying color. This is especially noticeable when the underlying color is dark.

Comment: Please share an example image and result pdf that demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Can you also share the actual PDF? And the actual original images? (Unfortunately uploading images to stack overflow converts them, so you'd need to share them otherwise, e.g. using public google drive or dropbox shares.)

Comment: I'm hesitant to provide a Pdf file publicly because it will have our company name, etc embedded in the licensing info. I could arrange to share it with an expert and/or an iText rep if the need arises. 

Original images are just .png files with xparent backgrounds that I had lying around, mostly made w/ Photoshop, for demonstration purposes. Nothing fancy about them.

Comment: The code you show is pretty short and should also run with an AGPL licensed iText. Thus, it should be easy to for you to create a short test program reproducing the issue with an anonymous result PDF. If that result PDF also shows the same issue, you can share it for analysis. If it does not, you know that there is something special about your input PDFs (if any) or in the code you don't show.

Comment: Seeing the images I would *guess* that there is a mixture of color spaces on your PDF page, e.g. a CMYK black backdrop and on it RGB images with transparency, without a preference of color space to resolve transparency effects in. The result of such a constellation differs when viewed on a RGB device (like a Monitor) and a CMYK device (like a color printer). But as said above, that merely is a guess.